# How to run cable from attic inside an external brick wall?

Tags: wiring

My exterior walls are brick. inside it's dry wall. My house was built in 1950.  I'm not sure what's between the drywall and brick but I'd like to fish a cable down from the attic to this wall where my TV is located.

I'd like to drill a hole through the attic down into the wall cavity and then down to a hole I will make in the drywall.

My concerns are, will there (should there) be any horizontal studs along this cavity? And what would you assume is behind the drywall (on an external wall made of brick) on a house built in 1949?

I've done this with interior walls before, but I don't know whats on the other side of an external facing wall.

Stud finder seemed to only have vertical slats

Comment: Are there bond courses (rows of bricks laid with their ends pointing at you instead of their faces) visible in the exterior wall?

Answer (score 2):

I would cut out a square the size of a single gang box in the drywall, at your target height and see what's behind.  Depending on what you find you can use a set of drill bit extensions until you hit the top plate, then you can pull the wire back down with the bit as a guide.

Worst case you find you can't do it and you can stick a low voltage, old work, box in its place and screw in a blank outlet cover.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This shows how a framed house with brick veneer is typically built

It is quite common for purlins to be nailed into the center of the wall between the studs.